# html element is not updating depending on input value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<p>`element that should contain whatever is written in the `<input>` box. The `<p>` does contain everything there is in `<input>` except the last character.

For example, (not valid JS code)

```
 if input = Fish 
    then p = Fis

if input = Monster
    then p = Monste
```

Here is my code

```
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function()
            {
                document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function()
                {
                    document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = document.querySelector('input').value
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" />
    </body>
```

How do I make the `p` element contain even the last character in the `input`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By registering to the 'keydown' event, your logic is firing when the key is pressed down, but the input box's value isn't updated until after your finger comes off the button.

Try registering to 'keyup' instead.

```
<script>
            window.onload = function()
            {
                document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function()
                {
                    document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = document.querySelector('input').value
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cb457Lpt/

Comment: Better event is `input`.

Comment: "Better" is subjective term, but yes it's also an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the last character from input value, and to add the resulted string in a html element, try this code:

```
<p id='id_p'></p>
<input type="text" id='id_inp' />
<script>
var id_inp = document.querySelector('#id_inp');
id_inp.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var str_inp = e.target.value;
  document.querySelector('#id_p').innerHTML = str_inp.replace(str_inp.substr(str_inp.length - 1), '');
});
</script>
```